# .Работа с классами

Tags: python

После добавления данного кода(•), возникла ошибка. Не понимаю в чём дело...

---

Ожидается, что класс `Button` будет корректно работать во всех модулях класса `Test`.

```
import pygame
from w import Button #•
from tkinter import *

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
        self.s_color =(0,130,130)

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20) 
         
        self.button = Button() #•
    
    def run_game(self):
            run = True 
            while run:
             for event in pygame.event.get():
                 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                     run = False
            
             
            self.screen.fill(self.s_color)
         
            t2 = self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Тест', True, (0, 0, 0)), (450, 600)) 
            pygame.display.flip()
            
             
ai = Test()
ai.run_game()
```

w.py :

```
from tkinter import *

class Button():

  def __init__(self):
    
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root_g = root.geometry("300x250")
    self.bth = Button(text="Test")
    self.bth_p = btn.pack()
    self.root_m = root.mainloop()
```

Ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/storage/emulated/0/pyhpn.v2/for work.py", line 29, in <«module>
>
> ai = Test()
>
> File "/storage/emulated/0/pyhpn.v2/for work.py", line 13, in _*init*
>
> self.button = Button()
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/
> aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/tkinter/
> *init*.py", line 2655, in **init**
>
> Widget.**init**(self, master, ‘button’, cnf, kw)
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/
> aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/tkinter/ init__.py", line 2577, in
> *init*
>
> self.tk.call( AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> ‘call’

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что в w.py, в классе Button(а он одноимённ с классом библиотеки tkinter), я пытался инициализировать класс с тем же именем, что породило ошибку. Я сделал следующее:

/w.py
Заменил имя моего класса на Knopka.

/Основной код
Также заменил имя класса на Knopka, во второй точке #•

Теперь всё работает